# I can't update MySQL database directly from C++ Builder XE application

Tags: mysql, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I have a database application written in C++ Builder XE languange called SpeZet. I use MySQL Remote Server database.

Sometimes I insert the data directly from SpeZet into the "tbtime" table on the Remote MySQL Server and it worked but when I try to update the record directly from SpeZet, I got any error message like this:

**Project SpeZet.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message 'Table 'SpeZet.tbtime' doesn't exist**

Whereas the tbtime table is really exists in the database.

When I try to continue the process, I got error message again like this:

**Project SpeZet.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Unable to find record. No key specified'**

Anyone can tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: If your table is named "tbtime" then why are you trying to insert into SpeZet.tbtime?

Comment: Can you put some code?